# Css, fixed menu and iPhone problems

Tags: html, css

I have problem with fixed menu and iPhone (with PC works without any problems).

Sometimes (not always) when i trying scroll menu (top or bottom) - scrolling no't menu, but content behind menu (main page content).

Menu looks like it stuck. iPhone lost focus on menu. 
Also i add "-webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch" - but did not help.

Code:

```css
html, body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 16px;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch !important;
        }
        #container {
            margin-top: 70px;
            height: 4000px;
            background: #4f7298;
        }
        i {
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        .dropdown-menu {
            display: none;
        }
        .open > .dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
        }
        li {
            width: 500px;
            height: 200px;
            background: #83987e;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #0A246A;
        }
        ul {
            overflow: hidden;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 100vh;
            z-index: 9;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch !important;
        }
        .dropdown {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            margin: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <i>X</i>
            </div>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="hidden-menu">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum<br>
        Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum<br>
        <div style="height: 1000px;"><br></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```